# Defining a function inside the input of another function in C

Tags: c++, c, function, input, function-pointers

I have a function which has a function pointer input. I can easily give function names to it as input. But I wonder if it's possible to define a function as input. For example I have a function like this;

```
void exampleFunction ( void (*functionPointer)( void ) ) {
  codes
  ...
}
```

Can I give an input like this inside the brackets? For example;

```
exampleFunction( void helloFunction ( void ) {
  printf("Hello");
} );
```

It gives compilation error like this but is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: "Other" ways implies that *this* is one.

Comment: OMG, good question. The more I see this stuff, the less I understand coding in C as opposed to C++. Don't use exceptions, virtual functions, or whatever, if you don't like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is impossible in C.

In C++, you can use a lambda-expression:

```
exampleFunction([](){ std::cout << "Hello"; });
```

Comment: Hahhahah! Thank you very very much!!! :D It actually worked, because I'm using Arduino IDE which also supports C++. I wrote some C code in C++ lambda-expression and it worked! I know it is not a good solution but I'm so happy right now :D Thanks again...